# What is better choice living place or salary in Sydney?

Tags: australia, working, cost-of-living, salary, socializing

I have a dilemma I have been given two offers of work one in CBD and other one in Hornsby both Sydney. I have a brother living in CBD so there for I would stay at first at his place, the time distance from his apartment to the office in CBD is 20 minutes by foot and to Hornsby 1,5 hour by public transport. The difference in salary is 30k annually. The one in CBD is 110k package and one in Hornsby is 140k package. What is a better choice? Earn less and live near CBD or earn more and live in Hornsby ? Please help I have a big problem with doing cons and pros over here.

Comment: I worked near[ish] Hornsby and chose to live in the CBD, but that salary difference is enormous. Could you take the Hornsby job and live somewhere in the middle of the train line? e.g. St Leonards? This way you still have access to the interesting parts of Sydney but you're not spending 30k per year on it.

Comment: Ye I think I can, for now I am staying in my brothers place and looking for an apartment. I don't know the area yet so well and it is hard for me to decide where to live and which job to take. I check the travel time with google maps. So you would took the larger salary in Hornsby ?

Comment: Can you extend on ur experiance ?

Comment: It wasn't a long experience, I did a 3 month fellowship in North Ryde and lived in Redfern. Longish commute (not as long as Hornsby), was made a lot easier by moving to St Leonards, and was still very easy to go into the city. Sydney is one of the coolest cities in the world, I'd want to live between Sydney and Hornsby to not lose access to Sydney. Just my opinion though. I miss Sydney every day.

Comment: so do you think that 50minutes one way travel time is worth 2k per month ?

Comment: I would take the Hornsby job, at least for long enough to gain experience to eventually (in a few years if you can) get a higher-paying CBD job. Maybe ask if telecommute is possible. And then I'd live somewhere in the outer part of Sydney, across the bridge from CBD, and just work on the train or read or stuff. But that's just me.

Comment: So to summarize is the 30k annually that much difference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the one with shorter travel distance.

This exact issue has been disused [on vlogbrothers by Hank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Am-6-jzR68) quite recently

Sources (taken from vlogbrothers):

> Homeownership doesn't increase happiness:
>   http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/14/rea...
>
> Short Commute = $40,000 raise http://www.npr.org/2011/10/19/1415144...
>
> Commuting Linked to Lower Life Satisfaction
>   https://uwaterloo.ca/recreation-and-l...
>
> Commuting and Metabolic / Cardiovascular Health
>   http://www.ajpmonline.org/article/S07...
>
> Commuting related to lower social activity and lower general trust
>   http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/artic...
>
> 10 Things Commuting Does to your Body
>   http://time.com/9912/10-things-your-c...